# Jsch Channel isClosed vs isConnected method

Tags: sftp, channel, jsch

In Jsch Channel class(https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html) there are 2 methods - isClosed and isConnected.

I think before calling connect() on the channel, both isClosed and isConnected return false.

Are there any other difference between both the methods? Are there any other cases where isClosed and isConnected don't return opposite results? Incase we want to check if a channel can be used which method is more reliable?